# Golang select case when reading from a chan and pushing to a chan

Tags: go

I was looking at how golang's select case statements work when you are pushing to channels and reading from channels. Sometimes it goes to the case where it reads from the channel and sometimes to the other one where it pushes to the channel (regardless of the order). Here are the both the cases:

- Reads from the channel: https://play.golang.org/p/2DL2JhgTtd
- Writes to the channel: https://play.golang.org/p/bl9idcpKO8

How does this work?

Comment: What do you mean "how does it work"? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If more than one of the `case`s is ready to proceed, one will be chosen randomly. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements.

Comment: @AndySchweig, I guess that answers my question. I didn't realize it was random, it might be due to how golang playground work. Maybe it's randomness is deterministic and I saw the same response everytime.

Comment: @JimB, I thought it would deterministicly choose either pushing to channel or reading from channel. It seems like it is random.

Comment: @baam: the playground caches each request.

Comment: You wouldn't want `select` it to prefer one over the other, otherwise the preferred direction would starve out the others in a mixed case like your example.

Comment: I see, this was really helpful. Thanks :)